# How can I make these columns fixed height?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I crreated this full-width section using Bootstrap 4. On large screen they look ok, but as I decrease the screensize the column heights are not equal. How can I make them equal heights so it will not affect if one contains more content than the other?

This what I see:
[image]

I tried to add 100% height to the services-3-box-wrapper class. Any help is appreciated.

```css
#services-3 {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#services-3 .container-fluid {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

#services-3 .service-box-1 {
    background-color: #199adb;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-right: 45px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-1 .sb-icon i {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 40px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-1 .sb-title {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-1 .sb-title h5 {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 19px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-1 .sb-desc p {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}


#services-3 .service-box-2 {
    background-color: #5eb8e4;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-right: 45px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-2 .sb-icon i {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 40px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-2 .sb-title {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-2 .sb-title h5 {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 19px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-2 .sb-desc p {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}


#services-3 .service-box-3 {
    background-color: #199adb;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-right: 45px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-3 .sb-icon i {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 40px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-3 .sb-title {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-3 .sb-title h5 {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 19px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-3 .sb-desc p {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}


#services-3 .service-box-4 {
    background-color: #5eb8e4;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-right: 45px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-4 .sb-icon i {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 40px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-4 .sb-title {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-4 .sb-title h5 {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 19px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-4 .sb-desc p {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="services-3">

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <!-- Service 1 -->
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="services-3-box-wrapper">
                    <div class="service-box-1">
                        <div class="sb-icon d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <i class="fas fa-user-md"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sb-title">
                            <h5>Qualified Doctors</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sb-desc">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit officiis error veniam praesentium saepe distinctio fuga doloremque ducimus rerum ad!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Service 2 -->
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="services-3-box-wrapper">
                    <div class="service-box-2">
                        <div class="sb-icon d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <i class="fas fa-ambulance"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sb-title">
                            <h5>Emergency Services</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sb-desc">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit officiis error veniam praesentium saepe distinctio fuga doloremque ducimus rerum ad!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Service 3 -->
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="services-3-box-wrapper">
                    <div class="service-box-3">
                        <div class="sb-icon d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <i class="fas fa-procedures"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sb-title">
                            <h5>In-patient care</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sb-desc">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit officiis error veniam praesentium saepe distinctio fuga doloremque ducimus rerum ad!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Service 4 -->
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="services-3-box-wrapper">
                    <div class="service-box-4">
                        <div class="sb-icon d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <i class="fas fa-user-nurse"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sb-title">
                            <h5>Friendly Staff</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sb-desc">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit officiis error veniam praesentium saepe distinctio fuga doloremque ducimus rerum ad!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>  

    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Strange, i test it and all work. Which size do you have issue?

Comment: yes even i also tested. its works

Comment: I added a screenshot to my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add these 2 rule to your CSS and it will fix the issue.

```
  .services-3-box-wrapper {
     height: 100%;
  }
  div[class^="service-box"]{
    height: 100%;
  }
```

actually Flex child automatically have the equal height but to inner items you have to make it 100%, and your were doing the right thing, but you have to make sure that the div which you gave background color need to have that height 100% property and all above parents of it as well.
Check this working

```css
#services-3 {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#services-3 .container-fluid {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

#services-3 .service-box-1 {
    background-color: #199adb;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-right: 45px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-1 .sb-icon i {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 40px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-1 .sb-title {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-1 .sb-title h5 {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 19px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-1 .sb-desc p {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}


#services-3 .service-box-2 {
    background-color: #5eb8e4;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-right: 45px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-2 .sb-icon i {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 40px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-2 .sb-title {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-2 .sb-title h5 {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 19px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-2 .sb-desc p {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}


#services-3 .service-box-3 {
    background-color: #199adb;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-right: 45px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-3 .sb-icon i {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 40px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-3 .sb-title {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-3 .sb-title h5 {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 19px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-3 .sb-desc p {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}


#services-3 .service-box-4 {
    background-color: #5eb8e4;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-right: 45px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-4 .sb-icon i {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 40px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-4 .sb-title {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-4 .sb-title h5 {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 19px;
}

#services-3 .service-box-4 .sb-desc p {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}
.services-3-box-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
div[class^="service-box"]{
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="services-3">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <!-- Service 1 -->
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="services-3-box-wrapper">
                    <div class="service-box-1">
                        <div class="sb-icon d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <i class="fas fa-user-md"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sb-title">
                            <h5>Qualified Doctors</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sb-desc">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit officiis error veniam praesentium saepe distinctio fuga doloremque ducimus rerum ad!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Service 2 -->
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="services-3-box-wrapper">
                    <div class="service-box-2">
                        <div class="sb-icon d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <i class="fas fa-ambulance"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sb-title">
                            <h5>Emergency Services</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sb-desc">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit officiis error veniam praesentium saepe distinctio fuga doloremque ducimus rerum ad!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Service 3 -->
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="services-3-box-wrapper">
                    <div class="service-box-3">
                        <div class="sb-icon d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <i class="fas fa-procedures"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sb-title">
                            <h5>In-patient care</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sb-desc">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit officiis error veniam praesentium saepe distinctio fuga doloremque ducimus rerum ad!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Service 4 -->
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="services-3-box-wrapper">
                    <div class="service-box-4">
                        <div class="sb-icon d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <i class="fas fa-user-nurse"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sb-title">
                            <h5>Friendly Staff</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sb-desc">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit officiis error veniam praesentium saepe distinctio fuga doloremque ducimus rerum ad!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>  

    </div>

</section>
```

example.